# My contract is deployed but instance is undefined

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, truffle-contract, openzeppelin-contracts

I have deployed a contract on the ganache blockchain successfully using truffle.

In the truffle console, I can call the contract fine

```
truffle(development)> MyCoin
[Function: TruffleContract] {
  _constructorMethods: {
    configureNetwork: [Function: configureNetwork],
etc.....
```

And even get the address like this:

```
truffle(development)> MyCoin.address
'0xdF7539B8cFA9566B36812ed123b020E633a8a0cf'
```

However, if I try and get an instance of the contract it returns undefined

```
truffle(development)> myToken = await MyCoin.deployed()
undefined
truffle(development)> myToken = await MyCoin.new()
undefined
truffle(development)> myToken = await MyCoin
undefined
```

My goal is to mint the contract, which doesn't work:

```
truffle(development)> MyCoin.mint(“0x63103644D45820EFb3cEBe188C7dA26F087797b4",100000);
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
MyCoin.mint(“0x63103644D45820EFb3cEBe188C7dA26F087797b4",100000);
                

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is `myToken` undefined? The result printed on the console is sometimes unrelated to the value being assigned. Also you should execute `myToken.mint(...)` instead of `MyCoin.mint(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed it creates the new instance despite returning undefined, made it work now

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why it returns undefined but this works and creates a new instance on the contract on ganache:
 `truffle(development)> myToken = await MyCoin.new()`

The error while minting was just a matter of changing the brackets:

`truffle(development)> myToken.mint('0x63103644D45820EFb3cEBe188C7dA26F087797b4',100000)`

It works now